# Get a thread dump in Browser JS?

Tags: javascript, browser

In Java there are utilities that can show you which code is executed by which thread by dumping the thread stacks. This allows to quickly understand what happens right now and is very useful for debugging purposes.

Is it possible to find out where current JS execution is?

Comment: Javascript is not multi-threaded.

Comment: You can use the debugger in the browser's Developer Tools. If a script is running, click on the "Stop" button to suspend it, and see where it is.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the only thread or multiple - still it's useful to know where it is. As for the debugger - you would have to know where to put a breakpoint. For that I first would need to find out where the execution is :)

Comment: You don't need to put a breakpoint. There's a "Stop" button that suspends script execution, and then allows you to browse the stack.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The trick was also to check Async checkbox. Could you please create an answer so that I could mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Developer Tools, check the Async checkbox and then you can use the `Stop` button at the left to suspend the script and examine its state while it's performing asynchronous actions like AJAX.

[image]